# Detect if the iPhone movement changes direction?

Tags: ios, iphone, motion-detection

In my app the iPhone is moved in two cases:

1. Moved in lineare direction
2. Moved in a arc direction

How can I detect whether the direction of the movement changes the direction?

Comment: I was just able to detect shake events.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to pull in the CoreMotion framework and start the device accelerometer and/or gyroscope.
[CoreMotion Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CoreMotion_Reference/)

What you'r looking to get is [CMAccelerometerData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAccelerometerData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMAccelerometerData). This is done by instantiating a [CMMotionManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMMotionManager/startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:) object and calling [startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMMotionManager/startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:)

Something like this:

```
CMMotionManager *manager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.5;  // half a second

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[manager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
    double x = accelerometerData.acceleration.x;
    double y = accelerometerData.acceleration.y;
    double z = accelerometerData.acceleration.z;

    // post back to main queue to update UI
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{           

    });
}];
```

You'll need to use some good old-fashioned geometry to detect arcs vs. lines.